# How to change name of document title on re-render using react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, use-effect

I basically want my document title to update when the value of an array I am displaying changes - I am rendering a list of orders on screen and when a user pushes a button it will change however many orders are displayed on screen.

I want the the number of products to be reflected in the document title so: "/(orderAmount)orders" would be name of the route in react router. orderAmount will change upon each re-render of new aray of orders displayed.

However it does not work as I get the error/warning: (No routes matched location "/()orders")

How do I get around this?

code below.

orders.jsx

```
import { Col, Row } from "antd";
import { useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import Order from "../components/Order";
import { AppContext } from "../context/Context";
import AntButton from "../elements/Button";
import ordersToDisplay from "../orders.json";

const OrdersPage = () => {
    const [filteringStatus, setFilteringStatus] = useState("");
    const {orderAmount, setOrderAmount} = useContext(AppContext)
    const [test, setTest] = useState("")

    const setDiplayAcceptedOrders = () => {
        setFilteringStatus("accepted");

    };
    
    const setDiplayCompletedOrders = () => {
        setFilteringStatus("complete");

    };
    
    const setDiplayInProgressOrders = () => {
        setFilteringStatus("inProgress");

    };


    const orders = useMemo(() => {
        if (filteringStatus) {
          return ordersToDisplay.filter((i) => i.orderStatus === filteringStatus);
        }
        return ordersToDisplay;
    }, [filteringStatus]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(orderAmount);
        console.log(orders.length)
        setOrderAmount(orders.length)
    })

    console.log("Orders to display: ", ordersToDisplay);
    console.log("test value: ", test)



    return(
        <div className="container">
            <Row justify="space-between" align="middle">
                <Col span={6}>
                    <h1>Orders</h1>
                </Col>
                <Col span={6}>
                    <AntButton onClick={setDiplayAcceptedOrders} name="Accepted"/>
                </Col>
                <Col span={6}>
                    <AntButton onClick={setDiplayInProgressOrders}  name="In Progress"/>
                </Col>
                <Col span={6}>
                    <AntButton onClick={setDiplayCompletedOrders} name="Complete"/>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col span={12}>
                    <h3>{filteringStatus == "" ? "All Orders" : filteringStatus}</h3>
                    {orders.map((e) => {
                        return(
                            <Order
                            key={e.id}
                            productName={e.productName}
                            dateOrdered={e.dateOrdered}
                            orderStatus={e.orderStatus}
                        />
                        )
                    })}
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
    )
}

export default OrdersPage;
```

app.jsx

```
import './styles/styles.scss'
import orders from "./orders.json";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-dom';
import HomePage from "./pages/home";
import OrdersPage from "./pages/orders";
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { AppContext } from './context/Context';


const App = () => {
    const [orderAmount, setOrderAmount] = useState("")

    const Routes = useRoutes([
        {path: "/", element: <HomePage/>},
        {path: `/(${orderAmount})orders`, element: <OrdersPage/>}
    ])
    
  return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{
            orderAmount, setOrderAmount
        }}>
            <div>
                {Routes}
            </div>
        </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

home.jsx (which is where the user initially clicks a button to take them to orders page

```
import { Col, Row } from "antd";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { AppContext } from "../context/Context";
import AntButton from '../elements/Button'

const HomePage = () => {
    const {orderAmount} = useContext(AppContext)
    console.log(orderAmount)
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <Row>
                <Col span={24}>
                    <Link to={`/(${orderAmount})orders`}>
                        <AntButton name="Orders" type="primary"/>
                    </Link>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: I noticed the route path discrepancy in your other question. Why are there parenthesis in the path? `"\`/(${orderAmount})orders\`"` doesn't seem correct. It should probably be something like `"/:orderAmount/orders"` where the `orderAmount` is a route path parameter. Then the link should be `to={\`/${orderAmount}/orders\`}` to match it. Either way, the parens should probably be removed.

Comment: Drew you really are coming to my rescue today!! I don't really understand your solution however. If it is not wrapped in parenthesis then it is just a string and is not the variable I am trying to use that changes upon rendering. If I use the solution you gave me the site does not work

Comment: I am using () brackets around it also just because thats what I want the number to be in so it would be "/(13)orders"

Comment: Would it be possible for you to try to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that we can't inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 0):

The bracket in the path is causing the problem. Per the docs,
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md

> () – Wraps a portion of the URL that is optional. You may escape
> parentheses if you want to use them in a url using a backslash \

If you insist on using the bracket you can escape it with

```
{path: `/\(${orderAmount}\)orders`, element: <OrdersPage/>}
```

Alternatively, if you just want the doc title to reflect order's information, you can check out https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet, which allow you to programmatically change the doc header to whatever you want without modifying the route.

Comment: I think I get what you are getting at, but this solution does not work. When applying this it still throws the routing error: No routes matched location "/()orders